# Learning Direct2D

Tags: api, windows-7, native, direct2d

I have some experince creating windows controls in GDI and now 
I'm looking for good resources (APIs, samples & good practices) to start learning about Direct2d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one
[Introduction Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861344.aspx)